# Why are the changes made in Xcode Storyboard not getting reflected on Simulator / Device?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I've designed a custom tableview using the storyboard. When app runs on simulator or iphone, the changes does not show up. It still displays last version of the tableview, which does not have Static Cells.

I've tried deleting */Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData* directory, cleaning build folder, deleting app on the iPhone and running again, restarting iPhone. Nothing works.

[Storyboard version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMhcz.png)
[What shows on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtAGN.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class NewDebtViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem


    let saveText = NSLocalizedString("Save", comment: "Save")

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: saveText, style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(saveDebt))
}

//Function to go back
@objc func saveDebt(){

    //Here the code for saving the New Debt

    //print("Back Button Clicked")
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 0
}

/*
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt fromIndexPath: IndexPath, to: IndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

What else to check or do?

[Runtime Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a61fr.png)

Comment: Your label, textfield inside the tableview?

Comment: Actually it just shows an empty uitableview.

Comment: Can you please check hierarchy of tableView and other view and upload document outline of your storyboard? you can check using debug view hierarchy at run time

Comment: The hierarchy actually show only the table separator.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Although I'm designing in the Storyboard the delegate code in the class where returning 0 for the number of rows so logically there were no rows in the iPhone:

This is the evil code which was commented for the problem to be solved.
      // MARK: - Table view data source

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 4
}
```

This is a screenshot for the runtime:
[iPhone Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRwjU.jpg)